Is there a way to repair small damaged spots on shingles?
Our roof has a few small spots where some of the top layer of shingle is worn off and white is showing through.  I find myself wondering if there is a product that can / should be used to simply patch over the top of these spots.  I haven't had much success searching online for such a thing, so perhaps it's not recommended?  Thanks!


Roofing tar should cover and prevent them from getting worst/leaking.  But it will stand out/not look good.

Some sort of impact damage (sticks, hail, bird) exposing the fibreglass layer, at a guess.
If you are the cautious and prepared sort  of owner that has a few spare shingles set aside to repair damage, cut a few chunks from one long enough to slide up under the top shingle (which you'll have to gently pry up on a nice hot day when they are flexible) and glue in place with roofing cement. Since the shingles are already "3D architectural" it's a practically invisible repair, if done right.
Otherwise you're going to have to buy an entire bundle of shingles in a hopefully-matching color to do that job well.

thanks!  so essentially cover it up with a piece of another shingle, if i understand correctly?  That makes a ton of sense, tho unfortunately we recently bought the house and haven't found a stash of matching shingles, hence looking for other options... but maybe i can find some to buy !
